Design: Aligning each row by hierarchy
In the screenshot attached, you will see the hierarchy of the audit area and if you notice there's a space in each audit area name if there's multiple associated key control and SCOTABDs in the audit area and currently having a hard to time to analyze how to solve this problem.

Here's the current data:
[
  {
    title: WARNING_MODAL.TABLE.AUDIT_AREAS,
    parent: ["Audit Area 1", "Audit Area 2"]
  },
  {
    title: WARNING_MODAL.TABLE.SCOTABDS,
    children: [{
      text: "SCOTABD 1",
      parent: "Audit Area 1"
    },
    {
      text: "SCOTABD 2",
      parent: "Audit Area 1"
    },
    {
      text: "SCOTABD 3",
      parent: "Audit Area 2"
    },]
  },
  {
    title: WARNING_MODAL.TABLE.KEY_CONTROLS,
    children: [{
      text: "Key Control Name 1",
      parent: "Audit Area 1"
    },
    {
      text: "Key Control Name 2",
      parent: "Audit Area 1"
    },
    {
      text: "Key Control Name 3",
      parent: "Audit Area 2"
    },
    {
      text: "Key Control Name 4",
      parent: "Audit Area 2"
    }]
  }
]

and here's the JSX code
{data.map((item) => {
  return (
    <Box>
      <ItemHeading>{item.title}</ItemHeading>
      {item.parent &&
        item.parent.map((parent, index) => (
          <Typography key={index} variant="body1">
            {parent}
          </Typography>
        ))}
      {item.children &&
        item.children.map((child, index) => (
          <Typography key={index} variant="body1">
            {child.text}
          </Typography>
        ))}

    </Box>
  );
})}

I want to achieve the same design I attached in this problem.
Current result:
Current Result

Transform original data and group them by parent. Here you have two variants of transformations that you could use:
A:
const data = [{
  [WARNING_MODAL.TABLE.AUDIT_AREAS]: ["Audit Area 1"],
  [WARNING_MODAL.TABLE.SCOTABDS]: ["SCOTABD 1", "SCOTABD 2"],
  [WARNING_MODAL.TABLE.KEY_CONTROLS]: ["Key Control Name 1", "Key Control Name 2"]
},
 // Same here for "Audit Area 2", etc.
];

// Order list, this also is mapped from the original source. Allows you to render the columns in the right order.
const order = [
    WARNING_MODAL.TABLE.AUDIT_AREAS,
    WARNING_MODAL.TABLE.SCOTABDS,
    WARNING_MODAL.TABLE.KEY_CONTROLS
];

B:
// Transform the data in the right order right away.
const orderedData = [
    [["Audit Area 1"],["SCOTABD 1", "SCOTABD 2"], ["Key Control Name 1", "Key Control Name 2"]],
    // Same here for "Audit Area 2", etc.
];

This way you have one row for each parent (Audit Areas) with all the respective children. All the cells can just fit the height of the row, this way you your problem is solved, you can use CSS Flexbox for a nice alignment.

I understand that it's an exercise for you, so try to find out all the steps for transformation and rendering by yourself. I just provided one of the milestones you have to arrive to, but the path must be walked by yourself.

If this answer satisfies your needs, choose it as the answer to your question, otherwise specify what else do you need.
